# MPI undefined object references

Tags: c++, c, fortran, mpi, fortran90

I'm trying to install a program (the Parallel Ice Sheet Model, or PISM) which uses MPI. I keep running into the errors

```
libpismutil.so: undefined reference to `ompi_mpi_cxx_op_intercept'
libpismutil.so: undefined reference to `MPI::Datatype::Free()'
libpismutil.so: undefined reference to `MPI::Comm::Comm()'
libpismutil.so: undefined reference to `MPI::Win::Free()'
```

when linking a CXX executable. I'm sort of stumped as to why this is occurring; the configuration for the program found where all of the MPI executables and libraries are located.

In another thread, someone suggested that this is due to different naming conventions when MPI is built with Fortran or C, but seeing as I have both `mpicc.mpich2` and `mpif90.mpich2` in my `/usr/bin` I would think this wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: What you say is slightly strange as ompi_mpi_cxx_op_intercept looks like an internal routine for openmpi, but mpicc.mpich2 suggests you are using mpich2. Could you clarify how you are compiling and linking, and how libpismutil.so was built? Secondly is http://www.cs.utah.edu/formal_verification/ISP-Eclipse/help/troubleshooting.html relevant? Finally you are aware that the MPI C++ bindings have been removed from the MPI standard?

Comment: @IanBush, although technically removed from the MPI-3 standard, implementers are free to continue to support the C++ bindings and most vendors would certainly do so, given the amount of parallel code, which uses the C++ MPI API (this question demonstrates the point). Of course it means that the new MPI-3 features would not make it into the existent C++ wrappers, at least not in a standard-defined way.

Comment: @HristoIliev - Yes, I realise that. It was more just to make sure the OP was aware of this in case he is extending PISM - writing new code dependent on deprecated or deleted standards or standard features is not the best plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much consternation, I've found the culprit. The program I'm trying to install uses a library for scientific computation called PETSc; the standard install of PETSc doesn't generate the shared object files needed by PISM, you have to explicitly tell it to make them. Once this was done, PISM installed correctly.

Of course, I was unable to run it because of some other obscure error with openmpi, but that's a story for another thread.